# Dynamically create MySQL table with python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

So I have an array of 200+ columns. How would I loop through this and create a table using `pymysql`?

Currently am connected like:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='my_host_name',
    user='my_username',
    password='my_password',
    port= 0000,
    database='my_db')

columns = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', .... ]
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE TABLE my_table (
       # For each column in columns                       
                             )'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Edit: I will loop through the columns first and append their appropriate data type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating mysql table from dynamic list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148964/creating-mysql-table-from-dynamic-list-python)

Comment: Do you want them to all be of the same type, e.g., `VARCHAR(255)` or something like that?

Comment: You should also specify at least the data type of each column in order to be able to create a table properly.

Comment: @GordThompson No. I suppose I will have to loop through first to get the data type and append it in the array

Comment: @Vincent - Then perhaps instead of a list of names you should have a dict where the key is the column name and the value is the column type.

Comment: @GordThompson I can create a list with the name and type, such as: ['FirstName VARCHAR(255),  'LastName VARCHAR(255)', 'Age int']. Would this be easier to work with than a dict?

Comment: @VincentNguye In this case you can use `sql = 'CREATE TABLE my_table (' + ', '.join(columns) + ');'`

Comment: @DanieleMurer okay, I will try that after I work on appending the proper data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to loop through all the columns:

```
columns = ['firstname VARCHAR(255)', 'lastname VARCHAR(255)'] # and so on
sql = 'CREATE TABLE my_table (' + ', '.join(columns) + ');'
```

Note that the resulting table is not even in 1NF (First Normal Form), as it doesn't have a `PRIMARY KEY`. It would be better to set one or more columns as `PRIMARY KEY` to reduce the risk of inconsistency.